# How do I change the value of <item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item> programmatically?

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

I am trying to take control over `android:windowLightNavigationBar` programmatically. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using;

```
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR)
```

or dark

Comment: Thanks. That is deprecated, but still works. How do I restore it back?

Comment: Use WindowInsetsController#APPEARANCE_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BARS instead.